# Access Query that brings up decimal amounts

Tags: ms-access

I'm working with a column of dollar amounts. They all have .00 at the end. I want to find amounts that have cents in there and not the .00

This is what I have before, and I don't know how I should modify it. This currently pulls up everything with .00

Table1.Amount Like "*.*"

Answer (score 2):

`Like` only works in text fields. You need a math solution like `Amount-Int(Amount) < 0.001`. It needs more modification if your `Amount` can be negative.

Comment: It works!  I used liked in the first place because my column was actually set to short text, not numbers. But I guess that didn't matter. Thank you!